# Adding multiple images inline with HTML and CSS

Tags: html, css

We have a project where we are trying to get 2 images to display on the same line. Currently, they are one on top of another.

```css
.footer-primary .awards {
  display: inline;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 47.5em) {
  .footer-primary .awards {
    float: left;
    display: inline;
    margin-right: 2.35765%;
    width: 82.94039%;
    margin-top: 1em;
  }
  .footer-primary .awards:last-child {
    margin-right: 0;
  }
}

.footer-primary .awards li {
  display: inline;
}

.footer-primary .awards li a {
  float: left;
  height: 10px;
  margin-right: 1.5em;
  width: 330px;
}

.footer-primary .awards li a.class1 {
  background: url("img1") 0 0 no-repeat;
  background-position: -6px 0px;
  height: 120px;
}

.footer-primary .awards li a.class2 {
  background: url("img2") 0 0 no-repeat;
  background-position: -6px 10px;
  height: 120px;
}
```

```html
<div class="community">
  <ul class="awards">
    <li>
      <a target="_blank" href="URL1" class="class1"></a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a target="_blank" href="URL2" class="class2"></a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a class="class3"></a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

How do we update the CSS to have img1 and img2 on the same line?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking debugging help should include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it within the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. Please see: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to display images on same line in html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39738361/how-to-display-images-on-same-line-in-html)

Comment: Your code works if the page is wide enough. Perhaps you are testing it with a screen that is too narrow?

Answer (score -1):

You could wrap the li elements around your images into a container div and add float values to the container and child elements like this

```
<div class="community">
  <ul class="awards">
   <div class="container">
    <li><a target="_blank" href="URL1" class="class1">TEST1</a></li>
    <li><a target="_blank" href="URL2" class="class2">TEST2</a></li>
   </div>
   <li><a class="class3">TEST3</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>

.container{
  float:left;
  width: 100%;
}
 .container li{
  float:left;
}
```

Comment: This may work but is invalid HTML. The only valid child of `ul` is `li`.